# How to use the correct ethnic words

Tags: single-word-requests

When referring to a few people in the workplace as Asians, not knowing their direct origin, I was reprimanded for racism how should I have addressed them as a whole.

Comment: One suggestion would be to not use a continent or a direction or a continental origin to refer to large groups of people.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. We need more details about what was said, where, to whom, and how, but ultimately this is not really a matter that is resolved through better understanding of English; native speakers stumble over often-shifting standards for terminology as well. Identifying someone by their ethnic background (or skin color, or gender, or sexuality, or income, or a thousand other things) *can* be taken as offensive because it seems to reduce the entirety of a person to a single immutable characteristic—one which may be associated with exclusion, negative stereotypes, or low social status.

Comment: Calling an Asian an Asian is racism?

Comment: Look up the word in several good dictionaries. Then ask on a related SE.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about the English language, but about etiquette, culture and political correctness.

Answer (score 1):

While the word 'Asian' can mean 'those of Asian descent' is is more often used to mean 'those from Asia', i.e. (assuming you are not in an Asian country) people born elsewhere.

If you refer to those who 'look Asian' as Asian, this can be interpreted as you assuming that people who look like that are not from your country. That can be quite offensive.

If you want to include those whose ancestry is Asian you can say "people of Asian descent' or 'of Asian ethnicity' or 'Asian ancestry'. But...

IMPORTANT NOTE

While not about language, and so not part of the answer, I very strongly recommend that in the workplace you do not refer to anyone, especially your colleagues, by their ethnicity without an extremely good reason. In virtually all workplaces the ethnicity of your co-workers should make no difference to you. If you have to refer to someone by their ethnicity, ask them what they would like to be called.

Comment: Are you saying "It's OK to be racist if you do it in a language the victims don't understand"?

Comment: I think this discussion is going to be long-winded and off-topic here. To make a long story, different languages are part of different cultures, and different cultures have different standards for appropriate and inappropriate discourse.

Answer (score 1):

This question is not about the word 'Asian' it is about the word 'racism'.

> A belief that one’s own racial or ethnic group is superior, or that other such groups represent a threat to one's cultural identity, racial integrity, or economic well-being; (also) a belief that the members of different racial or ethnic groups possess specific characteristics, abilities, or qualities, which can be compared and evaluated. Hence: prejudice, discrimination, or antagonism directed against people of other racial or ethnic groups (or, more widely, of other nationalities), esp. based on such beliefs. Cf. racialism n.

[OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/157097?redirectedFrom=racism#eid)

You are definitely not guilty of racism, according to what you have stated in your question. You may have been incorrect in your assessment of a group of people of 'Asian appearance'. But that is not racism.

The above definition deals with characteristics, abilities or qualities. The outward appearance is another matter.

In the course of my work I am obliged to identify unknown persons to the Police. And it is perfectly in order to identify someone according to their appearance. 'Of Asian appearance' is the correct way to do this.